# Transform AxiosResponse to String

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios

My application calls an API using `axios.get`, like below.
Is there a way to console.log `r` and `r.data` so I can view it as a `string`?

```
const r = await axios.get(k);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well what you need, you could use `JSON.stringify()`, like so:

```js
const r = await axios.get(k);
console.log(JSON.stringify(r));
console.log(JSON.stringify(r.data));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the response is a JSON object, you can just use `JSON.stringify()` to get the response data as a string.

```
const r = await axios.get(k);
const stringResponse = JSON.stringify(r)
```